# New /dev device file for random number generation

Tags: linux, random

I am trying to generate some one time pads in order to encrypt files using the vernam cipher. For that I am using the /dev/random generator in linux. As it is quite slow, I thought I may build a pseudo random generator of my own, for example using BBS or Yarrow.

Is there any way I can make them behave like /dev/(u)random, meaning can I create a device file from my chosen pseudo random generator algorithm?

Comment: If the devicecode is already in the kernel (or in a module) you can use mknod to create a directory entry that refers to the device {maj,min} node.

Comment: A PRNG cannot create an OTP; what you get instead is a stream cipher with a key size no larger than the seed of the PRNG.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [FIFO](http://linux.die.net/man/4/fifo) file that behaves like a pipe, i.e., that has different processes at the writing and reading end, with [mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo).